# Racket Function to Interact with SQL to INSERT new rows into a table

Tags: sql, racket

My goal is to write a function to insert the following value of the sql query in chunks.  The value is a join of two tables inserted into a new table.  I can get this function to work with a for loop in python (see below), but have no been able to write a Racket to SQL for loop that behaves appropriately.

Any guidance on how to write the python loop (below) as a racket for loop (or function) would be much appreciated!

```
### RACKET CODE THAT CURRENTLY DOES NOT BEHAVE AS PYTHON CODE BELOW ###
(for ((n 2)
      (length-of-table
      (vector-ref (car (query-rows      ;
      <SQL SERVER CONNECTION >                  ;
      "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesMOLREGNO) ;
      FROM mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete;")) ;
      0)))
     (in-query
      <SQL SERVER CONNECTION > 
      "INSERT INTO mjp_act_join_assay SELECT * FROM mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete LEFT JOIN mjp_assays_complete ON (mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesASSAY_ID=mjp_assays_complete.assaysASSAY_ID) WHERE mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesMOLREGNO>=? AND mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesMOLREGNO<=?;"
      n
      length-of-table
      #:fetch 100
      )
     )
```

```
#### PYTHON CODE THAT WORKS ####
#!/usr/bin/python 
import mariadb 

conn = mariadb.connect(
    user=<USER NAME>,
    password=<SERVER PASSWORD>,
    host=<HOST>,
    database=<SERVER NAME>)
cur = conn.cursor() 


sql_insert = "INSERT INTO mjp_act_join_assay SELECT * FROM mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete LEFT JOIN mjp_assays_complete ON (mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesASSAY_ID=mjp_assays_complete.assaysASSAY_ID) WHERE mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesMOLREGNO>=? AND mjp_drug_activities_mechanism_complete.activitiesMOLREGNO<=?;"

#insert information 
for i in range(10, 800, 10):
    print("Current value of i is:", i)
    try:
        cur.execute(sql_insert, (i,i+2)) 
    except mariadb.Error as e: 
        print(f"Error: {e}")
    conn.commit() 
    print(f"Last Inserted ID: {cur.lastrowid}")
conn.close()
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: ``` 
ERROR: in-query: query does not return rows
;   statement: "INSERT INTO mjp_act_join_assay SELECT * FROM ...
;   context...:
;    .../generic/interfaces.rkt:209:0: error*
;    .../generic/functions.rkt:90:0: compose-statement
;    .../generic/functions2.rkt:64:0: in-query-helper
;    call-with-values
;    .../private/arrow-val-first.rkt:555:3
;    for-loop
;    call-in-empty-metacontinuation-frame
;    eval-one-top
;    begin-loop
;    .../xrepl/xrepl.rkt:1478:0
;    call-in-empty-metacontinuation-frame
;    .../racket/repl.rkt:11:26
```

Comment: For my use of the racket code, do the value of the fetch call have to be a factor of the total number of id-key's that I'm joining on to prevent the iterator from failing on the last "chunk"?

Comment: Put the error message into your question not in the comment. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would translate your Python code:

```
(require db racket/dict)
(define sql_insert "INSERT INTO ....") ;; 2 parameters
(define conn (mysql-connect ....))

(for ([i (in-range 10 800 10)])
  (printf "Current value of i is: ~s\n" i)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail?
                   (lambda (e)
                     ;;(printf "Error: ~a\n" (exn-message e))
                     ;; Better way of showing exception in Racket:
                     ((error-display-handler) (exn-message e) e))])
    (define r (query conn sql_insert i (+ i 2)))
    (printf "Last Inserted ID: ~s\n"
            (dict-ref (simple-result-info r) 'insert-id #f))))
```

A few comments:

- Don't use `in-query` with SQL statements that don't return rows (like `INSERT` queries).
- Your Racket `for` loop clauses don't correspond to the Python code. I recommend reviewing Racket `for` loops, maybe practice with plain lists. (For example, your loop's body would execute at most twice. Do you see why?)
- Use `query-value` to get the value of a one-row, one-column query, like your `SELECT COUNT(...)` query.
- I don't see any "chunks" in your Python code, so I'm not sure what you mean by that.